# How to prevent contexmenustrip closing?

Tags: c#, listbox

I have a listbox with unnumbered items and a contexmenustrip. I wrote this code ( I know it seems too primitive, because of my inexpertness) It works fine but I have a little problem.
I want to make cms open at near your mouse position when you click on an item in listbox. and It will be opened at previous position when you click on blank. It is ok but cms is reopening by your each click. Is it posible to make it stay open when you click on blank not an item?

```
     public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    int a, b, tx, ty;
    int mx=0;
       private void listBox1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        b = a;
        a = listBox1.SelectedIndex;         

     if (listBox1.SelectedIndex != -1)
        {            
            if (a!= b)
            {

                contextMenuStrip1.Show(MousePosition.X + 10, MousePosition.Y);

                tx = MousePosition.X;
                ty = MousePosition.Y;
                mx =1;
            }
            else if (a==0 && b==0 && mx== 0)
            {
                tx = MousePosition.X;
                ty = MousePosition.Y;

                contextMenuStrip1.Show(tx + 10, ty);
                mx = 1;
            }
            else
            {
                contextMenuStrip1.Show(tx + 10, ty);
            }
        }       
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `AutoClose` property of `ContextMenuStrip` to prevent it automatically closing.

```
ContextMenuStrip cms = new ContextMenuStrip();
cms.AutoClose = false;
```

Then call `Close` method to manually close it

```
cms.Close();
```

Or handle the `Closing` event of contextmenustrip and set `e.Cancel = true` based on your condition

```
 void cms_Closing(object sender, ToolStripDropDownClosingEventArgs e)
 {
     if(your condition)
     {
         e.Cancel = true;
     }
 }
```

Comment: I created a bool cmscls . and then                                 void cms_Closing(object sender, ToolStripDropDownClosingEventArgs e)
 {
     if(cmscls==false)
     {
         e.Cancel = true;
     }
 }         and added cmscls=false into the last else{}.  it didnt work. anyway I may give up.